# HTML 5 video player fullscreen doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I've HTML 5 video player on web-site.

It has problem with full screen mode.

I've seen css from inspect element and height is 8px

```
-webkit-appearance: media-slider;
display: flex;
flex: 1 1 auto;
height: 8px;
margin: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: transparent;
min-width: 25px;
border: initial;
color: inherit;
```

How is it possible to make width and height 100% ?

Comment: Arent you just answering your own question? How about adding the styles `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;` to your `video` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `height: 8px` line and replace it with `width: 100%`.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hagapi/1/edit)**